# Why does OWA (Open World Assumption) can not infer in this case?

Tags: owl, ontology

Please consider this following ontology code from the book, [Foundations of Semantic Web Technologies](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/142009050X), page 130.

*(Selected pages of the book are available at [Google Books](https://books.google.com.bd/books?id=BdzL24RqcGIC&printsec=frontcover&dq=editions:QVes_CBJwS4C&hl=en&sa=X&ei=vQCXVIinApKHuASG0YHgCQ&ved=0CCAQuwUwAA#v=onepage&q&f=false).)*

```
<Person rdf:about="anton">
  <likesToWorkWith rdf:resource="doris" />
  <likesToWorkWith rdf:resource="dagmar" />
</Person>
<Person rdf:about="doris">
  <likesToWorkWith rdf:resource="dagmar" />
  <likesToWorkWith rdf:resource="bernd" />
</Person>
<Person rdf:about="gustav">
  <likesToWorkWith rdf:resource="bernd" />
  <likesToWorkWith rdf:resource="doris" />
  <likesToWorkWith rdf:resource="desiree" />
</Person>
<Person rdf:about="charles" />
<owl:Class rdf:about="FemaleColleagues">
  <owl:oneOf rdf:parseType="Collection">
    <Person rdf:about="dagmar" />
    <Person rdf:about="doris" />
    <Person rdf:about="desiree" />
  </owl:oneOf>
</owl:Class>
<owl:AllDifferent>
  <owl:distinctMembers 
      rdf:parseType="Collection">
    <Person rdf:about="anton" />
    <Person rdf:about="bernd" />
    <Person rdf:about="charles" />
    <Person rdf:about="dagmar" />
    <Person rdf:about="desiree" />
    <Person rdf:about="doris" />
  </owl:distinctMembers>
</owl:AllDifferent>
```

Now, in page 132 of the same book, a class, `Class2` has been defined.

```
<owl:Class rdf:about="Class2">
  <owl:equivalentClass>
    <owl:Restriction>
      <owl:onProperty 
      rdf:resource="likesToWorkWith" />
      <owl:allValuesFrom 
      rdf:resource="FemaleColleagues" />
    </owl:Restriction>
  </owl:equivalentClass>
</owl:Class>
```

As we understand, the members of this class will have *all* the colleagues they like-to-work-with from the class `FemaleColleagues`.

The inferences mentioned in page 132 of the same book based on the above ontology and class definition are:

1. `doris` and `gustav` do not belong
   to `Class2`.

Rightly said since both 
`doris` and `gustav`  have colleagues they like to work with *not* belonging to 
the class `FemaleColleagues` (`bernd` in both the cases).

2. Because of the OWA ([Open-World Assumption](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open-world_assumption)) we cannot say anything about the membership
   of `anton` or `charles` in `Class2`.

Under OWA we can comprehend the inference regarding 
`charles`. But it is somewhat difficult to comprehend the decision
regarding `anton`.
We can clearly see that *all* the members with whom 
`anton` like to work with, namely
`doris`  and `dagmar`,
 belong to the class 
`FemaleColleagues`.

Then  why can not we say that
`charles` belongs to `Class2`?

What is it I could be missing here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because it is possible that a male colleague has not been mentioned. There is nothing imposing a limit of only two on the colleagues anton likes, e.g., a cardinality restriction. So, the reasoner cannot prove that there is no male in that set, because it cannot prove that it knows all the individuals in the set.